# How do I draw a multi-column UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, grid, custom-cell

I want to draw a multi-column UITableView like the picture below, which is different than a common Custom Cell.

How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: is it **scroll-able**? If not, I don't think it's a `UITableView`

Comment: It is scroll-able. ^__^ If so, is this a UITableVIew? Very difficult!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it horizontally scrollable? It doesn't look so.

If it's only vertically scrollable, use a regular UITableView. For each row, you use a UITableViewCell as usual. For each column, just use a UIButton or any widget that you like. In your screenshot, it *looks* like columns but there is no underlying concept of columns.

You can easily create custom UITableView cells by using Interface Builder and loading a custom nib. Look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7 under the title "Loading Custom Table-View Cells From Nib Files".

Comment: Thank you! I use 5 UIButtons every row. so I success!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

http://usxue.is-programmer.com/posts/14176.html it will help you may be.

you can also see this link http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=153

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use UITableView, just add 6 items per row in your UITableViewCell.