# UITableView with multiple columns with flexible width and dynamic controls

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to have multiple columns in my `UITableView` but the `UITableView` supports only one column.
My app needs to have a `tableView` which stores staffs detail (tableView contains text boxes, comboboxes, checkboxes, buttons) for a particular project, user can add staffs and edit the necessary details.

Comment: You can use UICollectionView instead of UITableView. It is very flexible and customisable.

Comment: @NikolaKirev As I m new to iOS i don't know about UICollectionView, will i be able to delete or add or edit one entire row from UICollectionView?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634004/how-do-i-draw-a-multi-column-uitableview

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this library: https://github.com/Eclair90/Scrollable-MultiColumnTable-for-iPad

Comment: but can i add controls like checkboxes, buttons, drop downs etc to the different columns using this library?

Comment: You do have to alter the library for that. As you can see in the MCCell.m file it will add labels. You could modify that code to add other controls instead.

Comment: ok thanks for your suggestion but as i m new to iOS can you help me figuring it out because i don't know how to do this?

Comment: Maybe you should ask yourself the question if you really need multiple columns. You could also add multiple controls in a tableviewcell. That will probably be easier than changing the MCCell.m in the library. If you are looking for a tutorial to create complex tableviewcells, then have a look at this: http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/